# Highlight div if child element name matches location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm in an AngularJS web project.

I would like to highlight a `div` when clicking on an anchor link. The structure is as follows:

```
<div interaction-list-item="" sfinx-interaction="interaction" class="ng-isolate-scope">
...
<a name="iid_7923"></a>
...
</div>
```

And the anchor link sets the `location.hash` to the similar upon clicking, so a URL could look like this: `http://localhost:9000/#/home#iid_7923`. This `iid_` is dynamic, with different id's after the _

I've tried several jQuery solutions that ends up with really ugly and long code:

```
$(".indicator.active.line-D").click(function () {
    // more similar code..
    if ($("div:contains('D4')") && $("a:contains('D4')")) {
        $(".col-md-6.interactionscol:contains('D4')").css("border", "3px solid #428bca");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".col-md-6.interactionscol:contains('D4')").css("border", "");
        }, 1000);
    }
    // more similar code..
});
```

The purpose of this snippet is that upon clicking the anchor lnik, check for the div and anchor matching eachother and then apply CSS onto it, removing it after 1 second.

---

How could I do this smarter - if `location.hash` contains for example `#iid_7923` and the `div` with `a tag` which name has the same, highlight it!

I just can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

---

**UPDATE:** I would like to achieve similar to this: [target selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)

But my code for the anchor is not similar to the classical way.. it looks like this:

```
$scope.scrollToInteraction = function (iid) {
   $location.hash(iid);
   $anchorScroll();
};
```

Comment: In HTML5, you should use the `id` attribute instead of `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using angular, make your hash public in either a controller or for the whole application using the `$rootScope`:

```
angular.module('foo').run(['$location', '$rootScope', function($location, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.currentHash = function() {
        return $location.hash();
    };

}]);
```

And then in your html just use a directive to style your div:

```
<div data-ng-class="{'active': currentHash() == 'iid_7923'}">
```

Note the missing `#` in your currentHash().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this worked for me with smaller modifications. I put a div `<div ng-class="{'highlightDiv': currentHash() == 'iid_{{interaction.id}}'}">` and my function in the controller `$scope.currentHash = function() { return $location.hash; };` with corresponding css `.highlightDiv { border: 2px solid blue; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) event to add a class to the parent element.

```
var lastParent = null;
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    // Remove class from previous target parent
    if(lastParent)
    {
        lastParent.className = (' '+lastParent.className+' ').replace(' hastarget ',' ');
        lastParent = null;
    }
    // Remove the '#' from the location hash
    var targetId = document.location.hash.substr(1);
    var target = document.getElementById(targetId);
    // Try to support the name attribute
    if(!target)
    {
        var nameTargets = document.getElementsByName(targetId);
        // If nothing found, don't do anything
        if(nameTargets.length == 0) return;
        target = nameTargets[0];
    }
    // If the element does not have any parent, add the class to the <html> tag
    lastParent = target.parentElement || document.documentElement;
    lastParent.className += ' hastarget';
}, false);
```

#### [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y6cqh8hL/)